# How is X started on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg

I would like to know the exact process used by Ubuntu (if possible with location of configuration file) in order to start X (with lightdm).

I did not find any precise, detailed and comprehensive documentation of this process.

Some of the questions I would like to be detailed are :

- What scripts and configuration files are used (I mean where are they)?
- How to customize them in a clean way?
- How does X determine which graphics card (and thus the driver) it will use (since `xorg.conf` seems useless nowaday) on computer with integrated and discrete cards?
- How to force X to use a specific driver (in order to avoid lots of useless log messages)?
- What are the relations between the linux kernel driver and xorg graphics driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started answering this (as I do when I start answering a lot of questions on AU) because I wanted to know more. You've asked some pretty decent questions about *how things work* that I confess, I didn't immediately have answers to. I've done my best.

You'll understand what I'm talking about when you look at `man xorg.conf` and find things like this:

```
VIDEOADAPTOR SECTION
       Nobody wants to say how this works.  Maybe nobody knows ...
```

Seriously.

---

LightDM is started by Upstart (the `init` system, started by the Kernel on boot) here:

```
/etc/init/lightdm.conf
```

That feeds into the `lightdm` command which reads (seat information, etc) from:

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*
```

And then starts X which looks for the [following configurations](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml):

```
/etc/X11/<cmdline>
/usr/etc/X11/<cmdline>
/etc/X11/$XORGCONFIG
/usr/etc/X11/$XORGCONFIG
/etc/X11/xorg.conf
/etc/xorg.conf
/usr/etc/X11/xorg.conf.<hostname>
/usr/etc/X11/xorg.conf
/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.<hostname>
/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/*
/usr/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/*
```

If present in the configuration, that's how X would pick the driver/monitor/etc layout... If it's not, the newer XRandR extensions have a major part to play in guessing and persisting monitor settings.

If you don't want a best guess, you can force it in a direction by:

- [Telling xrandr to do something in particular](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73804/wrong-login-screen-resolution)
- [Blocking the wrong module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145821/how-do-i-force-x-to-use-the-vesa-driver) (eg the binary nvidia blacklists the free nouveau driver)
- [Setting up an xorg.conf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18361/force-x-to-use-second-video-card-so-i-can-pass-through-first-card-to-xen-vm)

But if you let `xrandr` handle things, once you log in, the configuration comes from:

```
~/.config/monitors.xml
```

After X starts there's a load of session gubbins (autostarts, etc) that start that aren't particularly relevant to the graphics process but they're probably worth mentioning. Mentioned.

There are two bits that elude proper explanation:

- The relationship between Xorg and Kernel drivers has made me go thoroughly cross-eyed. I found a [very exhausti{ve,ng} book on the subject](http://people.freedesktop.org/~marcheu/linuxgraphicsdrivers.pdf)[PDF!] but haven't had the time to even scratch it.
- How Xorg/XRandr picks the right driver.

There's certainly a lot more automagical wrangling than there used to be.